# Generate all possible MAC address within range

Tags: php, python, bash

It is a silly request. Yet, I ask hoping it might save my time and I can reuse if some one has already written and published in any opensource site.

I have a range of MAC address. Say for example

```
18:67:b0:7c:00:00 - 18:67:b0:7c:ff:ff
```

I need to generate all possible MAC address in the above range. Can anyone point me a free script that can do this?

Comment: It is easy to write such script. Have you tried to do this?

Comment: it is for a quick job. If it is freely available in github or opensource sites, written by someone it might save my time. If not I have to write it.

Comment: It literally takes 3 minutes to write such script. Lees time than you've spent writing the question and the comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With bash:

```
echo "18:67:b0:7c:"{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f}{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f}:{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f}{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

or:

```
printf "%s\n" "18:67:b0:7c:"{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f}{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f}:{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f}{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a Python 3.x version, just in case someone is curious:

```
import itertools

for x, y in itertools.product(range(256), range(256)):
    print(f"18:67:b0:7c:{x:02x}:{y:02x}")
```

Or for Python 2.x:

```
import itertools

for x, y in itertools.product(xrange(256), xrange(256)):
    print "18:67:b0:7c:{:02x}:{:02x}".format(x,y)
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with this very simple code. Just use nested loops and `sprintf()`.

```
<?php

$mac = "AA:BB:CC:DD:";
for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++) 
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < 256; $j++)
    {
        echo $mac . sprintf("%02X:%02X", $i, $j);
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}

?>
```

> Output:

```
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:00
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:01
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:02
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:03
...
AA:BB:CC:DD:7D:4A
AA:BB:CC:DD:7D:4B
AA:BB:CC:DD:7D:4C
...
AA:BB:CC:DD:FF:FD
AA:BB:CC:DD:FF:FE
AA:BB:CC:DD:FF:FF
```